# How to print a stack trace into the stderr from elisp?

Tags: debugging, backtrace

There are cases Emacs wont print stack traces on error

How can I make elisp print a stack trace from my own code? (into the stdout/stderr for example)

Something like Python's traceback:

```py
import traceback
traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Which cases? What's the use case of the function? (how Emacs (or elisp) can print to stdout/stderr?)

Comment: I wanted to avoid getting into the use-case because I'd just like to get the stack-trace in any context where I'm running elisp and not focus on the particular case why. I've run into a few cases where stack traces are totally ignored, asked about it here, and there wasn't a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure just what you're asking, but does using function `backtrace` in your code, at the place where you want to see a backtrace, help?  `C-h f` says:

> **`backtrace`** is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> `(backtrace)`
>
> Print a trace of Lisp function calls currently active.
>
> Output stream used is value of `standard-output`.

Comment: This is almost there, but prints to stdout instead of stderr. Instead you need `(let ((standard-output 'external-debugging-output)) (backtrace))`

Comment: @wasamasa: Yes, that info helps. (But the question does say, *"into the stdout/stderr for example"*.)

Answer (score 6):

```
(let ((debug-on-error t))
  (error "test"))
```

With `emacs -Q --batch -l tmp/test.el` the following is printed to stderr:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "test")
  signal(error ("test"))
  error("test")
  (let ((debug-on-error t)) (error "test"))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/wasa/tmp/test.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 44
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/wasa/tmp/test.el" "/home/wasa/tmp/test.el" nil t)
  load("/home/wasa/tmp/test.el" nil t)
  command-line-1(("-l" "tmp/test.el"))
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

If there's a situation where it doesn't work, chances are errors are inhibited by the code in question.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that gets the stack trace but doesn't cause the code to halt? - e.g: gets the stack-trace as a string?

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases, eg: in a function registered via `jit-lock-register`: `Error during redisplay: (jit-lock-function 1501) signaled (error "test")`

Comment: Hence the "chances are errors are inhibited by the code in question", popping up a debugger during redisplay is not an option.